# How to filter a TypeScript array based on maybe-undefined date-as-string item object property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The API returns the result as an object with more than thousand values in the following format:

```
result = {
  "items": [
            {
              "Name": "abc",
              "CreatedOn": "2017-08-29T15:21:20.000Z",
              "Description": "xyz"
            },
            {
              "Name": "def",
              "CreatedOn": "2021-05-21T15:20:20.000Z",
              "Description": "cvb"
            }
          ]
}
```

I would like to filter items in the object which are more than 90 days old without having to iterate all the items using for loop. In other words I would like to do something like this below but this doesn't work.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var newResult = result.items?.filter(function(i) {
    return ((currentDate - Date.parse(i.CreatedOn)) > 90);
}
```

According to the IDE property `CreatedOn` is of type `string | undefined` so it throws the error: Argument of type `'string | undefined'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'string'`. Type `'undefined'` is not assignable to type `'string'`.

Comment: "...without having to iterate all the items using for loop." -  `filter` still iterates through all the items btw. Or do you mean you just don't want to do it manually?

Comment: Please post the full TypeScript definition of `result` - that's where the `string | undefined` type is being set.

Comment: Whatever type you've identified `i` as has an optional field `CreatedOn`. Is it meant to be optional?

Comment: use something like Luxon see: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math?id=diffs

Comment: FYI 90 days is roughly 7,776,000,000ms which is what JS dates use as an internal value. Personally, I'd just create a `Date` instance that was 90 days old and compare the parsed dates to that... `const old = new Date(); old.setDate(old.getDate() - 90);`

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your project you'll have *something like* this:

```
interface Result {
    readonly items: readonly ResultItem[] | null;
}

interface ResultItem {
    readonly Name       : string;
    readonly CreatedOn  : string | undefined;
    readonly Description: string;
}
```

or this (or variations thereof):

```
type Result = {
    items?: ResultItem[];
}

interface ResultItem {
    Name       : string;
    CreatedOn? : string;
    Description: string;
}
```

<sub>Or it may be a `type` instead of an `interface` (just make sure you never use `class` to describe JSON data, as JSON `object` data cannot be a `class` instance because the constructor never runs).</sub>

<sub>Also, you should be using `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`, for member properties. So use names like `createdOn` instead of `CreatedOn` in your generated JSON.</sub>

Fortunately You don't need to change the types/interfaces, just change your TypeScript to *safely* check `.CreatedOn` **and** that `Date.parse` did not return `NaN`. Like so:

- The `result.items ?? []` part is because your post implies `result.items` is nullable or maybe-`undefined`.
- Note when using `map` with an `=>`-style function that you may need to wrap object-literals in `()` so the JS engine doesn't interpret the `{` and `}` as block delimiters.

```
const result: Result = ...

const currentDate = new Date();

const newResult = (result.items ?? []).filter( e => {
    if( typeof e.CreatedOn === 'string' ) {
        const parsed = Date.parse( e.CreatedOn );
        if( !isNaN( parsed ) ) {
            return ( currentDate - parsed ) > 90;
        }
    }
    return false;
} );
```

Though personally I'd do it with an initial `filter` and `map` steps:

```
const items       = result.items ?? [];
const currentDate = new Date();

const newResult = items
    .filter( e => typeof e.CreatedOn === 'string' )
    .map( e => ( { ...e, CreatedOn2: Date.parse( e.CreatedOn ) } ) )
    .filter( e => !isNaN( e.CreatedOn2 ) )
    .filter( e => ( currentDate - e.CreatedOn2 ) > 90 ) );
```

or simplified further:

```
const items       = result.items ?? [];
const currentDate = new Date();

const newResult = items
    .filter( e => typeof e.CreatedOn === 'string' )
    .map( e => Object.assign( e, { createdOn2: Date.parse( e.CreatedOn ) )
    .filter( e => !isNaN( e.CreatedOn2 ) && ( currentDate - e.CreatedOn2 ) > 90 );
```

---

**An even better solution:**

- If you're in control of how the JSON is generated then you can ensure that certain (or all) item properties will always be set (and so never `undefined` or `null`), so if you can guarantee that all 3 properties are always set (never `null` or `undefined`) then update your types/interfaces to this:

  ```js
  interface ResultItem {
      readonly name       : string;
      readonly createdOn  : string;
      readonly description: string;
  }
  ```

  - Note the `camelCase` properties.
  - *Immutability of data* is a huge benefit, so make sure your interface properties are all `readonly`, all arrays are `readonly T[]`, and that properties are only annotated with `?` or  `| null` or `| undefined` as-appropriate instead of simply assuming one way or another.
- **So make sure you use `strictNullChecks` in your `tsconfig.json` or `tsc` options!** - actually, just use `strict` always!
- Also consider changing your JSON DTO from using a `string` representation of a Date (are there any gurantees about timezone?) to being a natively readable Unix timestamp (in milliseconds), that way you can avoid problems with `Date.parse` entirely:

e.g.:

**Result.cs:**

```cs
public class ResultItem
{
    [JsonProperty( "createdOn" )]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; }

    [JsonProperty( "createdOnUnix" )]
    public Int64 CreatedOnUnix => this.CreatedOn.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
}
```

**Result.ts:**

```js
interface ResultItem {
    readonly createdOn    : string;
    readonly createdOnUnix: number;
}
```

```js
const ninetyDaysAgo = new Date();
ninetyDaysAgo.setDate( ninetyDaysAgo.getDate() - 90 );

const newResult = items.filter( e => new Date( e.createdOnUnix ) < ninetyDaysAgo );
```

...that way it's a single-line job.

---

The above can be made even simpler as Unix timestamps are just integers that are directly comparable, so `new Date()` can be avoided inside the `filter`, like so:

```js
const ninetyDaysAgo = new Date();
ninetyDaysAgo.setDate( ninetyDaysAgo.getDate() - 90 );
const ninetyDaysAgoUnix = ninetyDaysAgo.getTime();

const newResult = items.filter( e => e.createdOnUnix < ninetyDaysAgoUnix );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have interfaces defined like this...

```
interface Item {
  Name: string,
  Description: string,
  CreatedOn?: string // note the optional "?"
}

interface Result {
  items?: Item[] // also optional according to your code
}
```

and you want to filter for items that are older than 90 days (excluding those with no `CreatedOn`), then try this

```
interface ItemWithDate extends Omit<Item, "CreatedOn"> {
  CreatedOn?: Date // real dates, so much better than strings
}

const result: Result = { /* whatever */ }

const items: ItemWithDate[] = result.items?.map(({ CreatedOn, ...item }) => ({
  ...item,
  CreatedOn: CreatedOn ? new Date(CreatedOn) : undefined
})) ?? []

const dateThreshold = new Date()
dateThreshold.setDate(dateThreshold.getDate() - 90)

const newItems = items.filter(({ CreatedOn }) =>
  CreatedOn && CreatedOn < dateThreshold)
```

[TypeScript Playground Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnIBycGEAXMgM5hSgDmANPsgCISUK0AOYwA9iArVaIRswDCUCHEgATAPIgA-EJr1kAeg3IQfSMjAALFHx78QcADbIAREpu4AvrlyhIsRCgBK7AK6WwHGZgTEoVNEwAbQBdTW0rSj5kU14BK2REBD4oWXUwJIBPPl8oZCzZCCcXN2h4JAiIDAB1EMMWGRQIAA9IEFlKZHkMEIAedEaGW0lpOUUbAD4ggmmOhWUKdsgq3CyQamQpSn8wCh8jgOQAXiXbEMbKGwpI5gI8AnfbYlJH2zgAIwQNiYHwINhWsxAPxsACYAAwARgA7ABaWEADmR0IAnAAVeEAVjI0PhRNhADpYZSAFpAl7vGxsDjcVKQig2LoFABeDg%20jmB7zeIJsXwgUIqMFpIKmUlWczZcOJqPxmPheMJcNJFOpkqFjM4wDMAihCAAbn8ee9nARottdvs7hhKBRxs1WpsIDErgc-AEyQ6wmSMHAuAAKEPYZDgiBrSZkuMO5COACUV0W4eYcb9mH5UbWFFzimQSh0EAA7qwOiGCyAUxRfH0IDBQNGnEmU0pizEXHbArIOjjDIdDHxLLIvSAyxXICGk7g%205AB0OR7IyZQIGB3SH5xBF%20xh6OyXR15uU8jkFjYbOdgJ9hPSy6Btd-WSmwFoGGI9XEynLvMJDKIWQAAyIDIwA6NCxGZBt13Sh91kK87RHCAyUsPg6BDO8HyTIA)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance (and it's a pretty big hole of mine), what does `({ CreatedOn, ...item }) => ({` do, exactly? I've never seen the spread operator `...` used in a function parameter list at the same time as an object-literal.

Comment: @Dai extracts some named properties (`CreatedOn`) and keeps the rest in `item`. Basically a shortcut for `(obj) => { const { a, b, ...rest } = obj; ...`

Answer (score -1):

code is missing **)** of filter function

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var newResult = result.items?.filter(function(i) {
    return ((currentDate - Date.parse(i.CreatedOn)) > 90);
}  ) //<= misss
```

Comment: Your answer does not address `tsc`'s type errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).